# Unable to reference the object from coinmarketcap (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs

I have the following piece of code:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      coins: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({coins: data}));
  }


  render() {
    const test = this.state.coins[0];
    console.log(test);
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

test returns an object with id, name, etc like this:

```
{id: "bitcoin", name: "Bitcoin", symbol: "BTC", rank: "1", price_usd: "6545.84", …}
```

How can I access the name or id? I tried console.log(test.id) or console.log(test["id"] but they keep giving me errors.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
App.render
src/App.js:23
  20 | 
  21 | render() {
  22 |   const test = this.state.coins[0];
> 23 |   console.log(test.id);
  24 |   return (
  25 |     <div className="App">
  26 |       <header className="App-header">
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, include in your question the error received

Comment: by the time api returns data, render function would have been called and the coins would be empty. so `this.state.coins[0]` will throw error

Comment: this.state.coins[0] is not throwing an error, it returns the object I pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

The fetch is executed `asynchronously`. So, your componentDidUpdate should be like:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    async fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({coins: data}));
}
```

The problem that you're having is caused because when you try to get the coins, the request wasn't completed already. The `fetch()` and the `this.setState()` are asynchronous methods.

Comment: I tried it but getting the same error. I can access coins, I just can’t seem to access what’s inside it.

Comment: That's because when you try to access the id, it wasn't received already. When you `console.log()` the whole test, there's no problem, because it waits for the request.

Comment: Right, I understand now. But changing it to async didn't make any difference. I still get the same error.

Comment: You won't be able to do this, because the request isn't complete when you try to `console.log(test.id)`. Try to display the information inside the component rendering

Comment: define the state as `this.state = { coins: [ { id: 1 } ] }` and you'll see it